# Torch - Query matrix with another matrix

Tags: torch

I have a m x n tensor (Tensor 1) and another k x 2 tensor (Tensor 2) and I wish to extract all the values of Tensor 1 using indices based on Tensor 2. For example;

```
Tensor1
  1   2   3   4   5
  6   7   8   9  10
 11  12  13  14  15
 16  17  18  19  20
[torch.DoubleTensor of size 4x5]

Tensor2
 2  1
 3  5
 1  1
 4  3
[torch.DoubleTensor of size 4x2]
```

And the function would yield;

```
6
15
1
18
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first solution that comes into mind is to simply loop through indexes and pick the correspoding values:

```
function get_elems_simple(tensor, indices)
    local res = torch.Tensor(indices:size(1)):typeAs(tensor)
    local i = 0
    res:apply(
        function () 
            i = i + 1
            return tensor[indices[i]:clone():storage()] 
        end)
    return res
end
```

Here `tensor[indices[i]:clone():storage()]` is just a generic way to pick an element from a multi-dimensional tensor. In k-dimensional case this is exactly analogous to `tensor[{indices[i][1], ... , indices[i][k]}]`.

This method works fine if you don't have to extract lots of values (the bottleneck is `:apply` method which is not able to use many optimization techniques and SIMD instructions because the function it executes is a black box). The job can be done way more efficiently: the method `:index` does exactly what you need... with a one-dimensional tensor. Multi-dimensional target/index tensors need to be flattened:

```
function flatten_indices(sp_indices, shape)
    sp_indices = sp_indices - 1
    local n_elem, n_dim = sp_indices:size(1), sp_indices:size(2)
    local flat_ind = torch.LongTensor(n_elem):fill(1)

    local mult = 1
    for d = n_dim, 1, -1 do
        flat_ind:add(sp_indices[{{}, d}] * mult)
        mult = mult * shape[d]
    end
    return flat_ind
end

function get_elems_efficient(tensor, sp_indices)
    local flat_indices = flatten_indices(sp_indices, tensor:size()) 
    local flat_tensor = tensor:view(-1)
    return flat_tensor:index(1, flat_indices)
end
```

The difference is drastic:

```
n = 500000
k = 100
a = torch.rand(n, k)
ind = torch.LongTensor(n, 2)
ind[{{}, 1}]:random(1, n)
ind[{{}, 2}]:random(1, k)

elems1 = get_elems_simple(a, ind)      # 4.53 sec
elems2 = get_elems_efficient(a, ind)   # 0.05 sec

print(torch.all(elems1:eq(elems2)))    # true
```

Comment: This worked perfectly thanks a lot! I am doing this for 2D/3D interpolation of images and originally used a similar for loop structure but as you have said its a drastic difference!

Comment: A double tensor works fine but do you have any idea why this doesn't work properly for a cuda tensor?

Comment: @mattdns, what do you mean by "doesn't work properly"? I have no access to CUDA and thus cannot reproduce your problem. I can only guess. Cpu tensors are stored in memory the certain way - row by row. This defines how you flatten the indices. Cuda tensors might have their own structure. If it's true, you need different `flatten_indices` function. To find out if I am right, compare flattened cuda and cpu tensors: torch.all(float_tens:view(-1):eq(cuda_tens:view(-1)))